# Is there are way to open an iMessage extension from within the container app?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, ios10

So far I've been encountering scenarios where you can launch the embedding app from the extension using the openURL: method, but is there a way to achieve the opposite?

I'm interested in knowing whether it would be possible to do something in my container app that creates an MSMessage instance and launches my iMessage app extension. Is this doable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone else is interested, as of Xcode 8.0 beta 6, MFMessageComposeViewController declares a property message of type MSMessage that lets you create an interactive message from within a springboard application so it can be used to achieve what I wanted in the first place. It does not, however, let you open a container app application.

Here's my code:

```
let message = MSMessage()
message.url = // Your message url
message.layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
message.summaryText = // Summary text

let messageViewControler = MFMessageComposeViewController()
messageViewControler.message = message

show(messageViewControler, sender: self)
```

Comment: can you share example ? i am using MSMESSAGE but it cant open my parent application deep link

Comment: @grzegorz Do you have a code snippet to show how you accomplished this?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. You basically create and present a view controller with url that your app extension can read. I've added the code to my answer.

Comment: @grzegorz Using the method in the code above I get the message to pop up, but the iMessage app store is not selectable.  Have you seen this issue before??

Comment: @illis69 not sure I have. I've noticed that it's not tappable until a recipient is specified in regular iMessage.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible. You can read it in this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50375

Comment: Thanks for the link! As stated in my answer, I've decided to use MSMessage to do this but the solution is far from ideal.